# Can't install Strapi npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, strapi

i try to install strapi in my project and I got errors say

```
    Error while installing dependencies:
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v18.12.1
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-29T05_41_15_789Z-debug.log

 Keep trying!

Oh, it seems that you encountered errors while installing dependencies in your project.
Don't give up, your project was created correctly.
Fix the issues mentioned in the installation errors and try to run the following command:
```

I try to install node js and npm to change many versions but it still doesn't go away.
can you tell me what I mistake or missing install something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your npm is not compatible with your node version.

Did you tried updating your npm?

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```